Is it possible to symbolically solve this polynomial system of equations and inequalities with Mathematica?
I am solving the system
eq = {-y*(m - p) == 0, ((-x - y + 1)*k + x)*n + s*y - t == 
0, (k - x - y)*t - k*p + y == 0, (-m + n + y)*x + m - 1 == 
0, -(x + y - 1)*(p - t)*k + (-x - y + 1)*t + x*p == 0, 
y^2 + (-m - 1)*y + 1 + x*(p - 1) == 
0, (-x - y + 1)*t + (-m + 1)*x + y*n + m - 1 == 0, -k*n + s*x == 0};
ineq={0<k,0<m,0<s,0<x,0<y,0<n+(t-1)*p,0<(m*y-1)*n+(1-p)*(m*x-m+1),
0<(m*x-m-t+1)*p+m*y*(t-n),1<x+y,k<1,m<1,s<t,t<1};

in 14.1 on Windows. The command
Reduce[Union[eq, ineq], Reals]

has quit the kernel on my comp. The same issue with
FindInstance[Union[eq, ineq], {k, m, n, p, s, t, x, y}, Reals]

I have also  unsuccessfully been trying  to solve it step by step. Both
CylindricalDecomposition[ineq, {k, m, n, p, s, t, x, y}]

and
Reduce[eq, Reals]

are running without any response on my comp for hours. The question is motivated by that circumstance: Maple 2024 solves it (see that thread) .

Clear["Global`*"];
eq = {-y*(m - p) == 0, ((-x - y + 1)*k + x)*n + s*y - t == 
    0, (k - x - y)*t - k*p + y == 0, (-m + n + y)*x + m - 1 == 
    0, -(x + y - 1)*(p - t)*k + (-x - y + 1)*t + x*p == 0, 
   y^2 + (-m - 1)*y + 1 + x*(p - 1) == 
    0, (-x - y + 1)*t + (-m + 1)*x + y*n + m - 1 == 0, -k*n + s*x == 
    0};
ineq = {0 < k, 0 < m, 0 < s, 0 < x, 0 < y, 0 < n + (t - 1)*p, 
   0 < (m*y - 1)*n + (1 - p)*(m*x - m + 1), 
   0 < (m*x - m - t + 1)*p + m*y*(t - n), 1 < x + y, k < 1, m < 1, 
   s < t, t < 1};

sol = Reduce[
  Union[Reduce[eq] && Reduce[ineq]], {k, m, n, p, s, t, x, y}]

N@sol



k == 0.0536796 && m == 0.241142 && n == 0.540193 && p == 0.241142 &&
s == 0.0357708 && t == 0.44771 && x == 0.810644 && y == 0.637066


Thank you. NSolve[Union[eq, ineq], {k, m, n, p, s, t, x, y}, Reals,  MaxRoots -> 5] confirms it.

Maple produces the solution in terms of RootOf which is the analog of Root.

What are you using this problem for? What are you doing with the solution? Thanks.

Please ask the OP.
